# How can I search greater than or equal to values from same DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a C# WinForms Application and I need to get the greater than or equal to `>=` results from already shown values in DataGridVievw and display again them on the same DataGridView.

I tried all the possibilities in the below method but it works well for only `Like` condition. Is there any other method to display greater than or equal to results in the same `DataGridView`?

I am using Datatable as below.

```
DataTable dtSignages = new DataTable(); 
dtSignages.Columns.AddRange(
   new  DataColumn[4] 
   { 
       new DataColumn("OBJECTID", typeof(string)), 
       new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), 
       new DataColumn("Elevation_Difference_in_Feet",typeof(string)),
       new DataColumn("ElevationDifference", typeof(string)) 
   });
```

My CSV File Data is like. "1.0","ROAD CROSSING 1 BEGIN ","1.0","NO" "2.0","ROAD CROSSING 1 END ","2.0","NO"

Column Name is "Elevation_Difference_in_Feet" and is of type "String"

**Note:** I am reading the values from the CSV file to DataGridView.

```
((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Column_Name Like '%{0}%'", textbox.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: What is the column name and type you are trying to filter?

Comment: Check out this [System_Data_DataColumn_Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression)

Comment: I do not think you can simply replace the “LIKE” command with a “>=” command when using the “wildcard” symbol “%.” As I assume you are aware, the “%” sign in front of the search term will allow any number characters before the search term. This obviously works with `strings`, however this doesn’t make much sense when using the “>=” command. Therefore, in order to use the “>=” command, you need to remove the wildcards (%) or you will get an error.

Comment: In addition, it is not known from the give code what “type” of column `Column_Name` is and this will make a difference. IF the column “type” is of type `string`… THEN, the filter string:…`”Column_Name >= '{0}'", textbox.Text.Trim()`… will work without an error, however, it is NOT going to filter “numerically” as you would expect since the values are `strings.` Therefore, in order to successfully use a “>=” filter… the column’s “type” must be a “numeric” type.

Comment: The column “Elevation_Difference_in_Feet” appears to be a type of `Double`. From the `DataTable` definition in your comment… _”new DataColumn("Elevation_Difference_in_Feet",typeof(Double))”_ … You should “edit” your question and add the code that reads the CSV file and adds that data to the `DataTable` called `dtSignages`. It is recommended that you do NOT add addition “relevant” code to your question in the comments as others may not see It. “Edit” your question and add the complete code.